# How can I check if my server is alive with metricbeat, Is it possible?

Tags: nginx, alert, filebeat, elastalert, metricbeat

I've been using elasticsearch, metricbeat and elastalert to watch my server. I have nginx intalled on it that is been used as a reverse proxy and I need to send an to it if nginx drop or return some error, I have already some alerts configured but how can I make a rule to send alert to nginx  when it drop or return some error.
Thank a lot

Comment: Hi Diogo, please provide a clear description of what it is you are trying to do as it is not very clear at the moment. Have you looked at heartbeat for checking services health ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/heartbeat/current/heartbeat-overview.html

Comment: Sorry ben5556 for my description, I wanted to say if is possible to send alert using metricbeats and elastalert to my slack if my nginx drop or return some error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metricbeat is just for data about the system resources usage. What you need is installing filebeat and activating the nginx module. Then you can use the rule type `any` of elastalert and filter by `fileset.module: nginx` and `fileset.name: error`:

```
name: your rule name
index: filebeat-*
type: any
filter:
- term:
    fileset.module: "nginx"
- term:
    fileset.name: "error"
alert:
- "slack"
... # your slack config stuff
realert:
  minutes: 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help